# How to migrate back from initial migration in Django 1.7?

Tags: python, django, django-1.7, django-migrations

I created a new app with some models and now I noticed that some of the models are poorly thought out. As I haven't committed the code the sensible thing would be to migrate the database to last good state and redo the migration with better models. In this case the last good state is database where the new app doesn't exist.

How can I migrate back from initial migration in Django 1.7?

In `South` one could do:

```
python manage.py migrate <app> zero
```

Which would clear `<app>` from migration history and drop all tables of `<app>`.

How to do this with Django 1.7 migrations?

Comment: This is a case of you should have tried the command you wrote here. The answer and comment in it is pretty much a copy of this.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

You can do the same with Django 1.7+ also:

```
python manage.py migrate <app> zero
```

This clears `<app>` from migration history and drops all tables of `<app>`

See [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate) for more info.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? The django documentation on migrations is severely lacking...

Comment: Doc can be found in the django-admin and manage.py documentation page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate

Comment: How would you handle IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed?

Comment: it gives *Access is denied*

Comment: Just tried this on Django 1.9 and it worked fine as well. Thanks

Comment: This indeed dropped all tables and migration history, but it did not delete my `0001_initial.py` migration file. Could you please confirm whether I should manually delete it or not?

Comment: @sc28 Those can be manually deleted, edited, left, whatever you like.

Answer (score 7):

you can also use the version number:

```
python manage.py migrate <app> 0002
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate

Comment: The question asked is about migrating back from the *initial* migration, and using `0000` does not work

Comment: i see, i may have misunderstood the question (although it's not particularly well written IMHO).  why wouldn't you just drop the DB?  oh well

Comment: dropping the whole DB for one table is a bit overkill