# Django dropped table still exists

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Having problems with a model in one of my django apps.

I can make an instance of the model, but when I go to access it, I get an error:

```
# create and save model instance
user_form = UserSearchForm(user=user)
user_form.save()

# Then later
first_user_form = UserSearchForm.objects.all()[0]


(1146, "Table 'project.app_tablename' doesn't exist")
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://10.0.75.1:8000/search/
Django Version: 1.9.5
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
(1146, "Table 'project.app_tablename' doesn't exist")
Exception Location: /opt/project-venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in query, line 280
Python Executable:  /opt/project-venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/opt/project/project',
 '/opt/project-venv/lib64/python34.zip',
 '/opt/project-venv/lib64/python3.4',
 '/opt/project-venv/lib64/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/opt/project-venv/lib64/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/opt/project-venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 28 Mar 2017 22:50:16 +0000
```

I'm using Django 1.95 and I tried the following from the linked answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36565161/2516846):

1. Delete app migrations folder
2. Drop all app tables, e.g. DROP TABLE search_usersearchform
3. Delete all migrations from db: DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app = 'search'.
4. python manage.py makemigrations search
5. python manage.py migrate

But when I run migrate, it gives error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "search_usersearchform" already exists
```

Summary: Cannot create model again as relation already exists, yet cannot access model in my app as it says table doesn't exist

Is there a reference to this table/model stored else where which I need to remove? I don't know how the relation can already exist if I dropped the table, deleted migrations folder and removed migrations from db

#### EDIT

Okay finally got this sorted.

My project had two databases, the 'default' db, using postgres, and the 'secondary' db, using mysql.

When I created a new model in my app, and ran the migration, the table was added to the default db.
This allowed me to create an instance of the new model.

However when I went to access a previously saved instance, I got the error saying the table does not exist.

Turns out it was caused by my apps router.py, which redirected any queries to the 'secondary' db, which of course did not have the table.
To fix this, I added conditionals to the db_for_write and db_for_read methods in  router.py, to route those models to the 'default' db.

Comment: How are you accessing the table from Django? Show the code giving the error(s)

Comment: Sorry but what is this stacktrace ? `Request URL:    http://10.0.75.1:8000/search/` what is that ?

Comment: Can you just run those in a manage shell ? Also put your models please.

Comment: Did you delete the migrations folder or just the migrations files? If you just deleted the files, make sure to also delete the .pyc files

Comment: Yep deleted the full folder, how is it that I can delete the models table from the db and yet I can still run manage.py shell and create and import/create an instance of that model?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting or changing migration files that have that model in them, care with the dependencies. Then run again `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` it should create the model again. (We are talking about your test DB right?)

Comment: yes its a test DB, I've updated the question to show which steps I have tried

Answer (score 0):

make a back up of the models.py, delete the model code from the original models.py, then run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then simply restore the model code in models.py and run the above commands again.

Comment: I have tried removing the new model from models.py, and then running those commands, however when I add the model back, it says it already exists. Should I remove all models and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps should fix it:

- Remove the database.
- Create an empty one with the same name.
- Optionally, you may need to create a superuser for the new database.
- Remove the content of package migrations (not the entire package), except file init.py.
- Run command `python manage.py makemigrations`
- Run command `python manage.py migrate`